# New to Javascript and may be getting ahead of myself

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

Just started learning Javascript.  Currently, right now, I am working on two buttons and my goal is to insert an image into each of the buttons so that when you click on the button the image appears.

Here is the link to my jsbin: http://jsbin.com/vidupa/edit?html,js,output

not sure where I'm going wrong, or if I'm getting way ahead of myself here.

Comment: Please always post your code in your question.

Comment: this question shows little effort on trying to understand Javascript: you're using undefined variables and trying to pass strings as events instead of functions. To get you started:  [Declaring variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Declarations), and [eventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

I can't clearly say that I understand what you want to do, but I can see there several mistakes.

`showButton.addEventListener("click this fun vampire", showModal);`
"click this fun vampire" - this is not valid event type name. You probably wanted "click".

I think this should help you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

First parameter is type name of event you want to bind. 
The other parameter is your function that should process the event when it is raised.

The other thing that is not correct are ids. 
When you use ID="mickey" for button you can't use the same Id for image. 
Id should be unique for whole page.

If I can recommend to you, use jQuery. There are functions you are looking for.

For example: 
`$("#mickey").click(function(){
    $("img#mickeyImg").show();
    $("img#mickeyImg").hide();
});`